# Rotating a 3D direction vector upwards with `glm::rotate` and quaternions

Tags: c++, matrix, quaternions, glm-math, vectormath

Given the following coordinate system<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2z2J.png)</sup>, where positive `z` goes towards the ceiling:

[image: Coordinate system]

I have a `glm::vec3` called `dir` representing a (normalized) direction between two points `A` and `B` in 3D space<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EWqJ.png)</sup>:

[image: Two points in space]

The two points `A` and `B` happen to be on the same plane, so the `z` coordinate for `dir` is zero. Now, given an angle `α`, I would like to rotate `dir` towards the ceiling by the specified amount. As an example, if `α` is 45 degrees, I would like `dir` to point in the same `x`/`y` direction, but 45 degrees towards the ceiling<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xwt9.png)</sup>:

[image: Direction after rotation]

My original idea was to calculate the "right" vector of `dir`, and use that as a rotation axis. I have attempted the following:

```cpp
glm::vec3 rotateVectorUpwards(const glm::vec3& input, const float aRadians)
{
    const glm::vec3 up{0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    const glm::vec3 right = glm::cross(input, glm::normalize(up));

    glm::mat4 rotationMatrix(1); // Identity matrix
    rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(rotationMatrix, aRadians, right);
    return glm::vec3(rotationMatrix * glm::vec4(input, 1.0));
}
```

I would expect that invoking `rotateVectorUpwards(dir, glm::radians(45))` would return a vector representing my desired new direction, but it always returns a vector with a zero `z` component.

I have also attempted to represent the same rotation with quaternions:

```
glm::quat q;
q = glm::rotate(q, aRadians, right);
return q * input;
```

But, again, the resulting vector always seems to have a zero `z` component.

What am I doing wrong?

- Am I misunderstanding what the "axis of rotation" means?
- Is my `right` calculation incorrect?

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: Can you try `glm::normalize(input + glm::vec3{0.0, 0.0, tan(aRadians)})`? It should do the same.

Comment: Is `rotationMat` a typo?

Comment: @G.M.: yes, fixed. Sorry!

Comment: normalize the right vector before constructing your rotation matrix?

Comment: @noobius, `input` is already normalized - wouldn't `right` be normalized as well?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, not necessary that only is true if your input and up vectors are orthogonal and are unit vectors.  If they're not orthogonal then you would need to normalize the result.  I don't know what your input direction vector may be, so it's probably safe to normalize the result after doing a cross product.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to normalize your `up` vector because you defined it to be a unit vector, but you do need to normalize your `right` vector.

However, while I am unfamiliar with glm, I suspect the problem is you are rotating the matrix (or quaternion) around your axis rather than creating a matrix/quaternion that represents a rotation around your axis. taking a quick look at the docs, it looks like you might want to use:

```
glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(radians, right);
```